# Как в файле конфигурации модуля logging указать корректный путь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, логирование, python-3.8, cx-freeze

Python 3.8, для логирования используется модуль logging. Конфигурация задается в файле

```
[loggers]
keys=root, main

[handlers]
keys=fileErrorHandler, consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=notificationFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_main]
level=INFO
handlers=fileErrorHandler
qualname=main

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=notificationFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileErrorHandler]

class=FileHandler
formatter=notificationFormatter
args=("logs/errors.log",)

[formatter_notificationFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Но когда приложение запускается из exe после сборки в Cx_freeze автозапуском Windows, то родительской папкой для поиска "logs/errors.log" становится c:/windows/system32. Как в файле конфигурации можно определить место запускать приложения самого и определять, как запускается приложение?

В Python это решается так:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    dir_ = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)     # frozen
else:
    dir_ = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))    # unfrozen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только указав абсолютный путь.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/500489)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica является

Comment: "Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем _подробнее_ и понятнее он будет изложен, тем _лучше_."

Comment: В рамках работы с конфигурационным файлом, да, похоже вариантов нет. Альтернатива конфигурировать через  dictLogConfig. Документация: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging